# Pegar a margin do elemento anterior e somar mais um valor para o próximo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
         $("div#bloco div").css({
          "background-color" : "red",
          "height" : "50px",
          "width" : "50px"
         });
         $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top","10px")

         a();
     });
  function a (){
  $('div#bloco div').each(function(){

    var m =  $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top");  
    var seg =  $("div#bloco div:first-child").next();

    var total = $(seg).prev().parents().css("margin-top");
    var replace = total.replace("px","");
    console.log(replace)

    $(this).next().css({
      "margin-top" : replace + 46 +"px"
    });;
  })
}
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
div id="bloco">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

O objetivo é pegar o valor da margem da `div` anterior e soma +46 ao próximo elemento, exemplo:  valor da div 1 = 0 + 46 e atribuir à div2.

O problema é que todas as `divs` estão vindo com 46, o certo seria a segunda vim com 46, a terceira vim com 92 e assim por diante. Abaixo deixei o teste para vocês testarem. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
         $("div#bloco div").css({
          "background-color" : "red",
          "height" : "50px",
          "width" : "50px"
         });
         $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top","10px")

         a();
     });

  function a (){
  $('div#bloco div').each(function(i){
    
    var m =  $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top");  
    var seg =  $("div#bloco div:first-child").next();

    var total = $(seg).prev().parents().css("margin-top");
    var replace = total.replace("px","");
  

    $(this).next().css({
      "margin-top" : replace + 46 +"px"
    });;
    console.log("div: "+ i + " " + $(this).css("margin-top"))
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="bloco">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que fizeste alguma confusão no código. Veja uma forma simples de conseguir o que deseja. Fiz apenas algumas modificações no `each`.

Usando `parseInt`, você converte `10px` para apenas o valor `10`, por exemplo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("div#bloco div").css({
    "background-color" : "red",
    "height" : "50px",
    "width" : "50px"
   });
   $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top","10px")

   a();
});

function a (){
   var m =  $("div#bloco div:first-child").css("margin-top");  
   $('div#bloco div').each(function(i){

      var atual = parseInt($(this).css("margin-top"));
      var proximo = $(this).next();
      
      proximo.css("margin-top", atual+46+"px");
      console.log("div: "+ i + " " + $(this).css("margin-top"))
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bloco">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Era isso msm, estava usando o parseInt mas não dessa forma, me confundi na hora de converter. Obrigado!